keda-add-ons-http-interceptor pods are in CrashLoopBackOff - nost sure what is missing here
{"level":"info","ts":1733906885.9611363,"caller":"interceptor/main.go:44","msg":"starting interceptor","timeoutConfig":{"Connect":500000000,"KeepAlive":1000000000,"ResponseHeader":500000000,"DeploymentReplicas":20000000000,"ForceHTTP2":false,"MaxIdleConns":100,"IdleConnTimeout":90000000000,"TLSHandshakeTimeout":10000000000,"ExpectContinueTimeout":1000000000},"servingConfig":{"CurrentNamespace":"keda","ProxyPort":8080,"AdminPort":9090,"ConfigMapCacheRsyncPeriod":3600000000000,"DeploymentCachePollIntervalMS":250}}
W1211 08:48:05.962258       1 shared_informer.go:498] resyncPeriod 250ms is too small. Changing it to the minimum allowed value of 1s
{"level":"info","ts":1733906885.9623153,"caller":"interceptor/main.go:79","msg":"Interceptor starting"}
{"level":"info","ts":1733906885.962392,"caller":"interceptor/main.go:93","msg":"Fetching initial routing table"}
{"level":"error","ts":1733906885.9713888,"logger":"pkg.routing.GetTable","caller":"routing/config_map.go:82","msg":"failed to fetch routing table config map","configMapName":"keda-http-routing-table","error":"configmaps "keda-http-routing-table" not found","stacktrace":"github.com/kedacore/http-add-on/pkg/routing.GetTable\n\t/go/src/github.com/kedacore/http-add-on/pkg/routing/config_map.go:82\nmain.main\n\t/go/src/github.com/kedacore/http-add-on/interceptor/main.go:96\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255"}
{"level":"error","ts":1733906885.9714456,"caller":"interceptor/main.go:103","msg":"fetching routing table","error":"failed to fetch ConfigMap keda-http-routing-table: configmaps "keda-http-routing-table" not found","errorVerbose":"configmaps "keda-http-routing-table" not found\nfailed to fetch ConfigMap keda-http-routing-table\ngithub.com/kedacore/http-add-on/pkg/routing.GetTable\n\t/go/src/github.com/kedacore/http-add-on/pkg/routing/config_map.go:88\nmain.main\n\t/go/src/github.com/kedacore/http-add-on/interceptor/main.go:96\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581","stacktrace":"main.main\n\t/go/src/github.com/kedacore/http-add-on/interceptor/main.go:103\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255"}
